# Add commas while user typing numbers on Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have a On VF page input field called Amount. If user typing 99999 then it must return 99,999 how do I achieve this.

Any help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieve by using javascript :

**EXPLANATION** : This script will replace the number with comma after every 3 digits. Like 23,000,599,999. It will also allow you to enter a single . (dot) and will not allow you to add comma from your end.

```
    <script>        
    //This function is used to append comma with no after every 3 digit.
    function Comma(Num) { //function to add commas to textboxes
        Num += '';
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
        Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', ''); Num = Num.replace(',', '');
        x = Num.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1))
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        return x1 + x2;
    }

</script>
From the input text call the function.
```